# ¿Como puedo obtener el id de php y pasarlo a javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, id

Hola mi problema es que le asigne un id a un div en mi archivo html con php y quiero obtener ese id y si lo obtengo pero el div esta dentro de un bucle while y tan solo me imprime en pantalla el ultimo id o el primer id **este es mi código**

```
 $q = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER by id DESC ";
                       $consult = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);
                       while ($fila= mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){

                           //para elegir los nombre y la imagen del usuario
                           $q = "SELECT * FROM vende WHERE id = '".$fila['id_user']."'";
                           $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);

                           $filas= mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);

                             
                      
                       $fecha=$fila['Fecha'];
                       $titulo=$fila['Titulo'];
                       $precio=$fila['Precio'];
                       $descripcion=$fila['Descripcion'];
                       $producto=$fila['Producto'];


                        
                       ?>

                       <?php  
                        $comen = "SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE Public = '".$fila['id']."'";
                        $coment = mysqli_query($conexion,$comen);
                        $array = mysqli_num_rows($coment); 

                        
                       ?>

                          

               <div class="Hablen">

               <img src="<?php echo  $filas['Perfil']; ?>" height="45px" width="50px" style="border-radius:100px; border: 1px solid #d0d0d0; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px;" >

               <div class="nombre">
                 
                  <strong> <?php echo $filas['Nombre']; ?> </strong>

               </div>
               <div class="fecha">
                 
                   <p>Publicado el <?php echo $fecha; ?></p> 

               </div>
               <div class="titulo">
                 
                   <h1> <?php echo $titulo; ?> </h1>

               </div>

               <div class="descripcion">
                 
                <p> <?php echo $descripcion; ?></p>

               </div>

               <div class="precio">

                <?php if ($precio == letters ) { ?>

                  <h3 style="color:#28DD3B; position: relative; bottom: 80px; left: 10px; margin: auto;"><?php echo $precio; ?></h3>
                  
                <?php  }else{ ?>
                  
                   <h3 style="color:#28DD3B; position: relative; bottom: 80px; left: 10px; margin: auto;"><?php echo $precio; ?>$</h3>
                   
                  <?php } ?>
               </div>
              
            

               <div class="foto">

                    <?php 



                     if ($fila['NumerosDeProduc'] == 1) {

                     ?>
                     


                   <img src="<?php echo $fila['Producto'];?> " width="500px"height="450px" style="position: relative;bottom: 10px; left: 44px;  border-radius: 3px;  margin:auto;">



                   <?php   
                       
                     }else{

                     if ($fila['NumerosDeProduc'] == 2) {

                 

                     ?>

<div class="slideshow-container" id="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>">



<div class="mySlides fade">
 
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 2</div>
  <img src="<?php echo $fila['Producto'];?>"  style="width:100%">
  
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 2</div>
  <img src="<?php echo $fila['Producto2'];?>"  style="width:100%">
  
</div>



<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" id="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" >
  
  <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-left-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
             <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-4.5.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1H5.707l2.147-2.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708-.708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 .708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 0 .708-.708L5.707 8.5H11.5z"/>
            </svg>

</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)" >
  

  <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-arrow-right-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-11.5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h5.793L8.146 5.354a.5.5 0 1 1 .708-.708l3 3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-3 3a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8.5H4.5z"/>
            </svg>


</a>

<!--&#10094;-->

<!--&#10095; next-->


<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  
</div>

</div>

<script>

var slideIndex = 1;

showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {

  //estas son todas la formas que e provado 

 /*var si  =   $('.slideshow-container').attr('id');

 var no =  document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-container")[0].id;

 var nu =  document.getElementId("<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>");

 var ki = <?php echo json_encode ($a); ?>;

 */




 alert(variablejs);
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  


 



}

function currentSlide(n) {




  showSlides(slideIndex = n);



}

function showSlides(n) {
 
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
 
  if (n > slides.length) {
 
    slideIndex = 1
 
  }  
 
  if (n < 1) {
 
    slideIndex = slides.length
 
  }
 
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>






                    <?php

                   
                     }

                     }

                     ?>
                 
                
                  
               </div>


            </div>
```

quiero obtener el id es del div con la clase `slideshow-container` y luego pasarlo al script que esta mas abajo o obtenerlo con código javascript  para luego mostrarlo en pantalla y todo esto es un slider que esta dentro del bucle white y como hecho es con html css y js al momento de pulsar la flecha se mueve y recorre las 2 imágenes pero luego empieza a recorrer el slider de abajo esta es una imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y le quiero dar el id para que cuando le de **click a la fecha solo recorra las imágenes que tiene** y que no siga con las siguientes imágenes de otros imágenes
y el otro problema es que no me da el id de cada id por separado si no que con los demás métodos que e usado meda solo el ultimo id insertado o el primer id
mas no el id por separado de cada slider
**Que puedo hacer**

Comment: En teoría, esto es correcto: `var si = $('.slideshow-container').attr('id');`, siempre y cuando hayas cargado jQuery previamente. Solo falta ver cómo es que quieres usarlo posteriormente, por ejemplo: `alert(si);`. Necesitas ser más específico en lo que pretendes hacer; de ser necesario, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar más detalles.

Comment: hola  ya modifique la publicación me avisas si la entendiste

Comment: Se me ocurre que mientras recorras ese while, vayas creando un array para pasarlo por medio de `AJAX` ya que `php` funciona del lado del servidor y `javascript` del lado del cliente.

Comment: Necesitas editar nuevamente la pregunta para que incluyas todo el ciclo donde generas los _sliders_ y, de hecho, tu código _javascript_ no tiene la posibilidad de controlar más de uno.

Comment: ya puse todo el white desde que empieza hasta que termina. ¿Y sera que con jquery o ajax si funciona?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara y veo que esto se repite en varias partes: `id="<?php echo $fila['id']; ?>" >` al parecer sin cambiar de `$fila`. Si es así, estarías asignando el mismo id a varios elementos, lo cual es incorrecto, porque precisamente al querer luego seleccionar por un id repetido el código podría no funcionar de la forma esperada. Creo que falta contexto en la pregunta, por ejemplo, ¿de qué modo determinas en el cliente (Javascript) qué elemento hay que seleccionar? ¿No podrías asignar escucha de eventos a los elementos agrupados por una clase por ejemplo?

Comment: En pocas palabras lo que quiero es hacer un slider dentro a un while que cuando presionen la flecha solo recorra las 2 imágenes que tiene el problema es que dentro de while hay 7 mas porlotanto al pulsar una tecla recorre las dos imágenes y luego sigue con el otro slider